# Unable to load ssl cert in python: TypeError: certfile should be a valid filesystem path

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I am trying to send a POST request using client certificates (which are self-signed) in Python3. The application runs on Docker (although it should make no difference).

When I try to load the cert and key files in the context, I get the error below. I have verified that the certificates exist at the path /app in the filesystem. What is going wrong here?

**TypeError: certfile should be a valid filesystem path**

Here is my code:

```
import ssl

context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
context.load_cert_chain("/app/attendance.pem", "/app/key.pem")

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("someHost", 8200, context) # The error is thrown on this line
```

Comment: can you share the output of `ls /app/attendance.pem` & `ls /app/key.pem` to make sure the certs do exist?

Comment: `root@82a811ba2644:/# ls -ltrh /app/*.pem
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.3K Mar 28  2020 /app/attendance.pem
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.7K Mar 28  2020 /app/key.pem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("someHost", 8200, context) # The error is thrown on this line
> ```

From [the documentation of HTTPSConnection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPSConnection):

> ```
> class http.client.HTTPSConnection(host, 
>    port=None, 
>    key_file=None, 
>    cert_file=None, 
>    [timeout, ]
>    source_address=None, *, 
>    context=None, 
>    ...
> ```

Based on this the third parameter is `key_file`. This means your `context` will be interpreted as the key. This causes the error message you see since the context is no valid path. Instead of using a (wrong) positional parameter for `context` you should use a (correct) named parameter:

> ```
> conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("someHost", 8200, context = context)
> ```